# Another issue with RegEx in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am going through a RegEx issue... again.
Now, i am trying to search the following string:

```
"< < * < â€¢ 1 2 3 > <<0 12345Â®789>> * * < < 1 2 > <<0 123456<89>>*> >"
```

The 'rules':
The first part:
`"< < * < "`

Will be, as shown:
**two "<" one "*" and one "<".**
Between them, there might be from zero to 5 spaces.

The last part:  `"> > * > >"`

Will be, as shown,
**two ">" one "*" and two ">".**
Between them, there might be from zero to 5 spaces.

Finally, between the first and last part, `"â€¢ 1 2 3 > <<0 12345Â®789>> * * < < 1 2 > <<0 123456<89"` can be anything as shown.

I tried this code but it doesnt seem to work:

```
Pattern.compile("<\\s{0,3}<\\s{0,3}\\*\\s{0,3}<\\s{0,3}.>\\s{0,3}>\\s{0,3}\\*\\s{0,3}>\\s{0,3}>\\s{0,3}");
```

Any ideas?
Kid regards!

Comment: please format the writing and make it more readable, add your code attempt to the post and give a detail what you are actually facing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```java
<\s{0,5}<\s{0,5}\*\s{0,5}<(.*?)>\s{0,5}>\s{0,5}\*\s{0,5}>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OwKCiL/2).

In Java, define it as

```java
String regex = "<\\s{0,5}<\\s{0,5}\\*\\s{0,5}<(.*?)>\\s{0,5}>\\s{0,5}\\*\\s{0,5}>";
```

If you plan to match multiple lines between the left and right parts use the [`Pattern.DOTALL` option](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) when compiling the pattern.

*Details*

- `<\s{0,5}<\s{0,5}\*\s{0,5}<` - `< < * <` with zero to five whitesapces between the symbols allowed
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `>\s{0,5}>\s{0,5}\*\s{0,5}>` - `> > * >` substring with zero to five whitesapces between the symbols allowed.